# Acumatica Pass custom field vales into Cash Transaction detail table

Tags: reference, copy, field, acumatica

I have added two custom fields in the Screens: Payment and Application(AR302000), Cash Transactions(CA304000), Funds Transfers(301000) and Back Deposits(305000), and I pretend to add those fields also in the Table CATran

I have a Generic Inquiry that mimic the Report Cash Account Detail (CA633500) where I can see that the Field ExtReference and Description are copied from the Original Ducument (AR302000,CA304000,etc) to the CATran records.

If I would like to pass the value of my custom field to the CATran Table, to get the same behavior that the External Reference and Description does.

Does anybody know what is the action'name to override the Insertion of CATran Detail?

Comment: Behavior of which form you want to change?

Comment: I want to start with the Payment and Application Form (AR302000); and later Cash Transaction and Fund Tranfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form AR302000 uses following class: PX.Objects.AP.APPaymentEntry. It means that you should create extension for this class in way similar to this:

```
public class APPaymentEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<APPaymentEntryExt>
{

}
```

Then you can use extending with help of CATran_RowInserting for initial values configuration and CATran_RowInserted for modification of inserted values